# How to make python setuptools find top level modules

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a package with a structure that would (simplified) look like:

```
mypackage/
    __init__.py
    setup.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
    mysubpackage/
        __init__.py
        mysubmodule1.py
        mysubmodule2.py
```

I'm using a configuration for setup.py like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "mypackage",
    version = "0.1",
    author = "Foo",
    author_email = "foo@gmail.com",
    description = ("My description"),
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

The default `where` argument for `find_packages()` is `'.'`, but it doesn't include my top-level modules (module1.py nor module2.py). However, all child submodules and subpackages are added when running `python setup.py build`.

How could I get top-level Python modules added too, without moving setup.py one level higher?

Comment: Why don't you want to move `setup.py`? It should be *outside* the package.

Comment: To be fair, `setup.py` should be moved up one level higher and all other scripts / packages / modules need to be installed by configuring `setup.py` correctly. That should be it.

Comment: The `mypackage` in fact is a django app, and I'd like to have setup.py inside the app to commit it with the app's source and to avoid having it inside a django project of mine.

Comment: `setup.py` should always be at a higher directory level than your Python package.   Your app's "source" should be the Python package itself, *plus* any support files like `setup.py` or a `README` that would exist outside the Python package.  Have a look at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html

Comment: I've posted an answer with the working solution used based on your comments. Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you all for your responses.

Finally, I added a directory (not Python package) containing mypackage and the setup.py module. The structure now looks as follows:

```
myapp/
    setup.py
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        module2.py
        mysubpackage/
            __init__.py
            mysubmodule1.py
            mysubmodule2.py
```

Now using `find_packages()` works as expected. Thanks!