# Error when running Python FLEX Template: module from subdirectory cannot be found

Tags: python, dataflow

i am attempting to run a Dataflow job using Flex template, but i am getting stuck on a 'module not found error' and i cannot figure out why
so here is the structure of my directory

```
|__ modules
  |____ edgar_quarterly_form4.py
  |____ __init__.py
|__ main.py
|__ setup.py
|__ __init__.py
```

my main.py has this import in its code

```
from modules import edgar_quarterly_form4
```

and here's my dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base

ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}/modules
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY spec/python_command_spec.json ${WORKDIR}/python_command_spec.json
COPY modules ${WORKDIR}/modules

ENV DATAFLOW_PYTHON_COMMAND_SPEC ${WORKDIR}/python_command_spec.json

RUN pip install avro-python3 pyarrow==0.15.1 apache-beam[gcp]==2.27.0

COPY __init__.py ${WORKDIR}/__init__.py
COPY setup.py ${WORKDIR}/setup.py 
COPY main.py ${WORKDIR}/main.py
# Super important to add these lines.
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_SETUP_FILE="${WORKDIR}/setup.py"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/main.py"
```

And here's my setup.py file

```
import setuptools

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
'numpy',
'beautifulsoup4',
'pandas',
'sendgrid==6.2.1',
'lxml',
'pandas_datareader',
'apache-beam[gcp]==2.27.0',
]
setuptools.setup(
   packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
)
```

However, every time my template runs i am getting this error

```
368, in load_session module = unpickler.load() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load obj = StockUnpickler.load(self) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 827, in _import_module return 
 getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 
 'modules'
```

And i cannot figure out why.
I have added some echos to my docker file to see if all of the files have been copied, and all the files have been copied successfully to the image... so i cannot really figure out what's going on
Please note i am getting exacty the same error even if the edgar_quarterly_form4.py file is in the same directory as main.py

kind regards
Marco

Comment: Check if the following solution would work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71839761/7611838

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seeems that with beams 2.27 this solution does not work
Instead, you shoudl follow what is outlined in this thread

[Including another file in Dataflow Python flex template, ImportError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64895504/including-another-file-in-dataflow-python-flex-template-importerror)

you'll have to add a setup_file parameter to your metadata, and pass a
--parameter setup_file=